# LinkedIn Reporting Ad Analytics API get by company id

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm using the reporting API for LinkedIn to get what companies have clicked on my ad and I'm using this endpoint [Reporting Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/ads-reporting?view=li-lms-2023-08&tabs=http)

1. [https://api.linkedin.com/rest/adAnalytics?q=analytics&dateRange=(start:(year:2023,month:3,day:28),end:(year:2023,month:9,day:30))&timeGranularity=DAILY&accounts=List(urn:li:sponsoredAccount:123456)&pivot=MEMBER_COMPANY&projection=(*,elements*(externalWebsiteConversions,dateRange(*),impressions,landingPageClicks,likes,shares,costInLocalCurrency,approximateUniqueImpressions,pivotValues*~(localizedName)))&fields=externalWebsiteConversions,dateRange,impressions,landingPageClicks,likes,shares,costInLocalCurrency,approximateUniqueImpressions,pivotValues](https://api.linkedin.com/rest/adAnalytics?q=analytics&dateRange=(start:(year:2023,month:3,day:28),end:(year:2023,month:9,day:30))&timeGranularity=DAILY&accounts=List(urn:li:sponsoredAccount:123456)&pivot=MEMBER_COMPANY&projection=(*,elements*(externalWebsiteConversions,dateRange(*),impressions,landingPageClicks,likes,shares,costInLocalCurrency,approximateUniqueImpressions,pivotValues*%7E(localizedName)))&fields=externalWebsiteConversions,dateRange,impressions,landingPageClicks,likes,shares,costInLocalCurrency,approximateUniqueImpressions,pivotValues)

and I have tried to change accounts=List(urn:li:sponsoredAccount:123456) to companies=List(123456) but I'm getting an error  message: "Array parameter 'companies' value '11259469' is invalid. Reason: Deserializing output '11259469' failed",

I wonder how can I use the same endpoint (1) but only for one company based on it's id?

Answer (score 0):

If we look at the documentation example request we see that the params containing list have actually an encoded URI format so instead of `List(urn:li:sponsoredAccount:123456)` it should be something like `List(urn%3Ali%3AsponsoredAccount%3A123456)` , you can use the `encodeURIComponent()` function for that.

Also for companies it should probably be 'organization' and not 'sponsoredAccount' so `companies: List(urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A123456)`